# Timestamp showing a date 12 years in the future

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my code:

```
select 

  event_date,
 
  DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp), "Asia/Karachi") as datetime_tstz
from 
`app.analytics_317927526.events_intraday_*`
where
event_timestamp=(select max(event_timestamp) from `app.analytics_317927526.events_intraday_*`

)
```

So the event_date is showing 20240318. And the datetime_tstz is showing 2036-06-03T07:06:23.005627.

Please note, I have disabled the cached results as well.

Comment: What's the actual value of this event_timestamp? If you `SELECT MAX(event_timestamp)` from this table then what value is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely your data/query problem.

Check this out:
select unix_micros(TIMESTAMP "2036-06-03T07:06:23.005627 Asia/Karachi") => 2096089583005627

If your datetime_tstz is resulting into "2036-06-03T07:06:23.005627" then its likely comes from your subquery output. Your subquery produces max value of event_timestamp in micros.

(If your source data is in UTC you have to check for UTC version of your micros output value with your source data.)

See this: when everything is in sync it just works:

```
select 
DATE(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp_in_macros), "Asia/Karachi")) as event_date, 
DATETIME(TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp_in_macros), "Asia/Karachi") as datetime_tstz
from 
(select unix_micros(TIMESTAMP "2036-06-03T07:06:23.005627 Asia/Karachi") as event_timestamp_in_macros)
```

Another thing to check if your event_date and event_timestamp are connected or not. If event_date is not derived from event_timestamp, then its another data issue.